# why reverse_iterator cannot assign a new value using forward iterator?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, stl

we can create a new reverse_iterator from forward iterator:

```
set<int>::iterator fiter = si.begin();
set<int>::reverse_iterator rsiter(fiter);
```

but we can't assign a new  forward iterator to it:

```
rsiter = fiter;    //cannot compile
```

is there any reason for it?

Comment: because it's constructor is [explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1y7x448.aspx)

Comment: why reverse_iterator not support operator=(iterator)?

Comment: See this doc for detail: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/reverse_iterator

Comment: Thank you. I mean is there any concern why c++ standard not support reverse_iterator::operator=(iterator)?

Comment: @camino: is there any need? It is not hard to type: `rsiter = std::reverse_iterator(fiter);`

Answer (score 0):

From  [reverse_iteraor's documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/reverse_iterator)

1. `explicit reverse_iterator( Iterator x );`

The constructor is `explicit`, which means it cannot called implicitly by doing something like:

```
set<int>::reverse_iterator reverse_iterator it = si.begin(); // error
```

You must always call the constructor explicitely:

```
set<int>::reverse_iterator reverse_iterator it(si.begin()); // works
```

Overloading `operator=()` does not seem productive IMO, it just confuses the interface.

Answer (score 0):

`reverse_iterator` is an iterator adapter.

`iterator` is an iterator.

It wouldn't make sense if you could assign an iterator to an adapter: they're not the same thing. C++ made it possible to pass an iterator for the adapter to adapt:

```
// adapter rsiter can adapt iterator fiter
reverse_iterator rsiter(fiter);
```

Comment: An iterator adapter is also an iterator. If it makes sense to construct a reverse iterator from a forward iterator, it can also make sense to assign it. It's a design choice, not an issue of sense/nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

As [David Rodríguez - dribeas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36565/david-rodriguez-dribeas) says in his comment, there is no need to overload the assignment operator when you can just use the copy assignment operator. `auto` to reduce typing.

```
auto rsiter = std::set<int>::reverse_iterator(fiter);
```